# RawText "" must be wrapped in an explicit <Text> component [React-Navigation]

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Getting an error `RawText "" must be wrapped in an explicit <Text> component.` while navigating inside the StackNavigator using React-Navigation, and navigation does not happen, the navigation gets stuck in between the screens, producing this collision at the place of back button:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dynamic `headerTitle` of one of the screens in the stack and at the time during navigation, the variable that is assigned to `headerTitle` is equal to `''`, this kind of error will pop-up, so simply locate the place of empty string value assignment, remedy it and your problem should be solved.